# localStorage won't save divs cloned with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, clone, local-storage

I am trying to create a small web app that will allow users to create a list of movies they want to see. So far, I've been able to get the list to be sortable and I've implemented the ability to add divs to the list. I've also been able to use localStorage to save the first div, but not the rest. The rest are clones of the first.

My JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#movie-list").sortable({
        handle : '.handle',
        update : function(){
        var order = $("movie-list").sortable('serialize');
        }
    });
    $("#add").click(function(){
        $(".movie").last().clone(true).insertAfter($(".movie").last());
    });
    $("#save").click(function(){
        var titles = $(".title").html();
        var divs = $(".movie").html();
        localStorage.setItem("UserTitles", titles);
        localStorage.setItem("divs", divs);
        alert("Your list has been saved!");
     });
     $(function(){
        if (localStorage.getItem("UserTitles")){
            var titles = localStorage.getItem("UserTitles")
        }
        else if (localStorage.getItem("divs")){
            var divs = localStorage.getItem("divs")
        }
        else{
            var titles = "New Movie";
            var divs = $(".movie").html();
        }
        $(".title").html(titles);
     });
});
```

My HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="header">MY MOVIE LIST</div>
    <div id="movie-list">
        <div class="movie">
            <img src="http://aux4.iconpedia.net/uploads/74429410244335194.png" width="16" height="16" class="handle" alt="Move" />
            <label class="title" contenteditable="true"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="savelist">
        <img id="save" src="savelist.png" />
    </div>
    <div id="addmovie">
        <img id="add" src="addmovie.png" />
    </div>
</body>
```

Ideally, I want the user to press the "Save" button and have the divs that exist, their order, and their contents saved using localStorage.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding a question here, but also, you aren't reinitializing anything from `localStorage.getItem("divs")`

Comment: The question is basically "What am I doing wrong?" And how do I fix that. I've been coding for probably a good 7 months, so I'm still a greenhorn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `$(".movie").html()` will only give you the html for the first element found of the class movie. Instead, you want to use the `each` method to iterate over each element found. This can be done with the following:

```
var allHTML = "";
$(".movie").each(function(i) {
  allHTML = allHTML + this.innerHTML;
});
```

You can find additional documentation at http://api.jquery.com/each/.

**Update**

I reworked your ready function a bit to save the entire movie list and then reload it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#add").click(function(){
        $(".movie").last().clone(true).insertAfter($(".movie").last());
    });
    $("#save").click(function(){
        var titles = $(".title").html();
        var divs = $("#movie-list").html();
        localStorage.setItem("UserTitles", titles);
        localStorage.setItem("divs", divs);
        alert("Your list has been saved!");
     });
     $(function(){
        var titles = "New Movie";
        var divs = $("#movie-list").html();
        if (localStorage.getItem("UserTitles") != null && localStorage.getItem("divs") != null)
        {
            titles = localStorage.getItem("UserTitles")
            divs = localStorage.getItem("divs")
        }
        $(".title").html(titles);
        $("#movie-list").html(divs);
     });
});
```

I found two issues with your code. One, your `localStorage.getItem("UserTitles")` call was blocking the call to `localStorage.getItem("divs")` since you used an `else if`. Two, when you check for the `localStorage.getItem` values you need to check them against `null`. I also made a small change by storing the entire contents of the `movie-list` div in `localStorage`.

Comment: So I tried the `each` method. And it didn't work. How should it be implemented in the context of localStorage? I'm missing something and I don't know what.

Comment: Reworked the function a bit to show how to save and load the divs. Please take a look and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Great. Please accept the answer if there is nothing else you need.